# Local quotient of arithmetical ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

A commutative ring $R$ with $1$ is said to be arithmetical  if for all ideals $a  , b$ of $R$,     $ a   ∩ ( b   + c   ) = ( a   ∩ b   ) + ( a   ∩ c   )$ or the localization $R_m$   is a uniserial ring for every maximal ideal $m$   of $R$. Now let $x\in R$, where $R$ is an arithmetical ring. Is there condition under which $\frac{R}{ann_R(x)}$ is a local ring, where $ann_R(x)=\{r\in R: rx=0\}$?

Comment: Other than the trivial one?  It seems whether or not $ann_R(x)$ is contained in exactly one maximal ideal depends heavily on $R$ and $x$. What is the connection with the ring being arithmetical?

Comment: when $R$ in uniserial, it is true. I want to consider the local case.